# Register a dll on the target installation

Tags: c#, setup-project

I have a Windows service that I've written in C#.  In the business logic, I have a reference to a dll that needs to be registered on the target installation.  Currently, it's not being registered on the target machine.  On the setup project, I opened the Properties for the dll in question and noticed a 'Register' option that was set to "vsdraDoNotRegister".  Should I change this value to "vsdraCOMSelfReg"?

Comment: It is a COM dll.  It should be registered on the target machine based on the "vsdrfCOMSelfReg" setting.  I'm not sure if the Interop for the COM dll needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

If your DLL is a simple class library DLL in c#, then no you should not try to register the DLL.  If your DLL is compiled as a COM library then you should register it.

Comment: It is a COM library.  I actually have the dll set to "vsdrfCOMSelfReg".

Comment: @jmac: Yes turn the option to `vsdraCOMSelfReg`

Comment: Originally, I was looking at the Primary Output when I said that it was set to "vsdraDoNotRegister".  The COM dll is set to "vsdrfCOMSelfReg".  Do I have to change anything on the Interop COM dll?